# ASP.NET MVC 6 Conditionally set disabled attribute when using tag helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I'm just starting to use ASP.NET MVC Tag Helpers which are great, but I cant work out how to conditionally set boolean attributes like the disabled attribute.

For example I have a tag helper that looks something like this:

```
<input asp-for="MyProperty" disabled="disabled" />
```

But I only want the `disabled` part to be present when for example, `@Model.IsDisabled` is true.

How do I do this?

Comment: Model.IsDisabled (the entire model has a property signed as IsDisabled) or the specific input inside the model Model.SomeInput.IsDisabled ?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34866539/asp-net-conditionally-disable-a-tag-helper-textarea

Comment: Thanks - that question did it - don't know how I missed it!