# Enable disable controls in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

Recently I have started to work on show/hide, enable/disable controls based on logged in users role and its assigned permissions. While browsing on the net lot of people have provided to create the custom html helper and also the latest introduced tag helpers.

So, my question is can i show/hide, enable/disable controls using TagHelpers ? or do i need to write html helper only.

Right now I have implemented it as follows using the traditional method

```
@if (!permissions.CheckPermission("course.coursedetails.mytextbox.visible"))
{
  <section class="col col-5">
  <label class="label">@objLocalizer["Title"]</label>

  <label class="input">
  <i class="icon-append fa fa-tag"></i>
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CourseLang.CourseTitle, permissions.CheckPermission  ("course.coursedetails.mytextbox.enabled") ? (object)new { @disabled = "disabled", @class = "form-control", @id =   "mytextbox" } : new { @class = "form-control", @id = "mytextbox" })

  <span asp-validation-for="CourseLang.CourseTitle"  class="text-danger"></span>
  </label>
  </section>

}
```

As you can see I have checked the required permission in `@Html.TextBoxFor`,
However this logic is not applicable on all types of controls like `select, label` etc.

So, how can i make a common approach/class to achieve this thing by using tag helper/html helper ?

Comment: I would use tag helpers. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34868369/5426333

Comment: @adem caglin is this applicable for Html.TextBoxFor, Html.DropdownlistFor also ???

Comment: As far as i know, you can't. For html helpers you need to find another solution(i don't know how to implement the same for html helpers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the built in authorization pieces you can do this using the IAuthorizationService.

First, you'd need to swap out whatever permissions.CheckPermissions() is, and go back to the [claims based authorization](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/introduction.html) built into asp.net core. Assuming you need something more than a simple claims check then you'd use [code policies and requirements](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/policies.html) to express your rules, then finally you check those policies [inside your views](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/views.html), wrapping the controls you wish to stop rendering with the checks.

Don't forget you need to duplicate the checks in the controller code, because otherwise developer tools in browsers can be used to add the controls back, regardless of what you rendered in the first place.