# Taghelper attributes must be well formed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, tag-helpers

I am using Razor pages in .net 5.0

I wanted to use anchor tag helper to generate `href` as shown below

```
<a asp-page="/Add" class="ml-4 d-lg-block" @* something *@)"
```

When add any c# code with tag helper it is giving a compile error
in this I have added `@* something *@` but it is giving a compile error

and also If I use any condition to render a tag, It is throwing compile error

```
<a asp-page="/Edit" @(Model.Condition?"":"disabled")>
```

saying compile error : The taghelper 'a' must not have c# in the elemnts attribute declaration area

How can I use C# along with tag helpers to satisfy both of the above condtions

Comment: The thing is, I should only use tag helper, not `href`. Can you please suggest any other

Comment: Does this answer your question? [asp.net conditionally disable a tag helper (textarea)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34866539/asp-net-conditionally-disable-a-tag-helper-textarea)

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax you have to use to conditionally add the `disabled` attribute:

```
<a asp-page="/Edit" disabled="@Model.Condition">...</a>
```

When condition is true it will generate:

```html
<a href="..." disabled="disabled">...</a>
```

and when condition is false it will generate:

```html
<a href="...">...</a>
```

Keep in mind that anchor elements do not have a `disabled` attribute so you have to add additional CSS to disable them:

```css
a[disabled] {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

This solution is explained in more detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10276157/10839134

Comment: While your answer is technically correct, the overriding detail is that there simply isn't any `disabled` attribute on HTML's `<a>` element, so it has no effect at all.

Comment: That's true, but you can use the attribute in a CSS selector like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35746332/10839134

Comment: That's a horrible abuse of `pointer-events: none;` - and it doesn't stop keyboard navigation either.

Comment: `pointer-events: none;` is the most popular solution for disabling anchor elements: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10276157/10839134

Answer (score 0):

`disabled` will not work for a tag,you can try to use a button,and add `window.location.href` in onclick:

```
@if(Model.Condition==""){
    <button onclick="window.location.href='/Edit'" >...</button>
 }else
{
    <button onclick="window.location.href='/Edit'" disabled">...</button>                
}
```